# Proper way to run a Discord bot featuring multiple source scripts

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I am working on a project that is essentially serving like a Java project where there will be a "main" file and several bot features written by each group member, individually. I am relatively new to Python programming, so I am welcoming suggestions if there is a better format/work flow for us to follow.

I have studied some thorough examples of Discord bots and my understanding is that the `client.run()` or `bot.start()` functions are blocking, and thus having each feature/script run those functions will be counterproductive. As mentioned above, the goal here is that each member can upload their feature to our Github and then the features will be incorporated into the main Bot script as seamlessly as possible.

The two thoughts that I have are:
  1) Have each script written as a function, and the main script will be the bot calling those functions on each event.
2) Have each script define a bot object and then create instances of those objects in the main script. This could be troublesome though (if my understanding is correct) as each one would have to have their own `loop.run` or client definitions

Any suggestions here would be more than appreciated.

Comment: Can you expand on what the “features” would be?

Comment: Honestly it's still in a development stage, but I know one of them will be to randomly generate a sentence at random times, and another one will be to post messages, gifs, and/or memes on command. (This is meant to be a fun project, as you can tell)

Answer (score 1):

With discord.py you can use the [cogs feature](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html), which will allow you to create groups of commands that can be easily added to the bot with `bot.add_cog(Cog(bot))`.

Comment: In other words each of the features should be listed as a command, and then in the main file registered with the `bot.add_cog` feature? 
Or are you saying that each feature should be made as a bot, and then the `Cog(bot)` will add each individual bot to the main one?

Comment: The cogs system doesn't create a new bot. It is a way to organize features that you can then load into your bot with the `bot.add_cog()` method. If you refer to the documentation I linked, it explains how to do everything.

Comment: I looked it over, but I don't follow the example it gave. I will do further reading and then comment again if I have follow up questions.

Comment: Also perhaps I was unclear with my first comment. If I am reading your response correctly, each feature/bot will be in the auxiliary scripts and then the main will add the cogs to the main bot. Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: That is correct. [Here is an example of everything working in concert.](https://gist.github.com/EvieePy/d78c061a4798ae81be9825468fe146be)